# I am using firebase and Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a registration form, and I wish the administrator can enable or disable (via code, from his account inside the app) a user when asked to register.

In other words, I would like that the registration of a user can be approved (via code, not using the Firebase console) by a administrator before become effective.

How can I get this? I did not found sufficiently complete answer to this question.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like something you'll have to build yourself.

Comment: Your question is quite broad, and answering it would require describing how to do many things and/or designing a large program. While there's probably a way to do all of that, you should break the problem down into smaller problems, and try to solve those. When you get stuck, ask a question about that specific part. Include what you've done so far (with code!). Describe the exact behavior you want for that part, as well as how that differs from what happens with the code you have. Include the exact text (with [stack traces](/a/23353174)) of any errors. See the [FAQ] and [ask] for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of things you need a user to:

Sign up > Await Approval > Enter Main app

A potential way of implementing this would be to have them sign up using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) then within your splash activity each time the app is started have it check for a boolean value within firebase database of either true or false.

If true - they are authorised and they go to the main activity, if false then they go to the waiting screen.

How you implement the approval process is up to you but essentially your Approver will just need to turn the boolean value from false to true.